# How can I deactivate cookies used for authentication in php?

Tags: php, class, authentication, cookies

I would like to apologize in advance if this is a stupid question, but I am a junior developer starting a new job (and yes, very afraid of making a huge mistake). Most of my expertise is in Python, SQL, JavaScript, CSS and HTML. However, in my job I've been tasked with deactivating cookies in their website (they have to because of privacy laws in Europe). Some of the pages' backends are written in javascript and I was able to find the cookies and deactivate them, but some are written in php. I can tell what the code is and what it does, but since I've never dealt with php before, I'm not sure if I should just delete the script or if I should modify it in any way. Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. This is the code (it is in its own file):

```
<?php

    // Real-time Data Aggregation (RDA)

    // error_reporting( E_ALL );
    // ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    class RDA {
        private $session_cookie = '';
        private $log_site = '';
        private $config = array();
        private $raw_payload = '';
        private $payload = array();
        private $publish_path_map = array();
        
        public function __construct($config){
            $this->config = $config;
        }
        
        public function process(){
            $this->raw_payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
            
            if(!$this->is_json($this->raw_payload)){
                echo 'Expected payload was not provided. Script has been aborted.';
                return;
            }
            
            $this->payload = json_decode($this->raw_payload);
            
            if(array_key_exists('passed_through_rda', $this->payload) && $this->payload->passed_through_rda == 'true') return; // If this had previously passed through a RDA script so let's abort to prevent recursion.
            
            if($this->is_test_payload()) return; // When the Test button is clicked from account settings simply echo back the payload and abort.
            
            $this->send_next_webhook_request(); // forward payload to another webhook listener.

            if($this->payload->finished != 'true') return; // we only want to react when the event has finished and not when it has been started.
            
            $this->set_publish_path_map(); // sets up an index of publish paths to use as reference to prevent publish recursion.

            foreach($this->config['actions'] as $action){

                if(!$this->payload_contains_trigger_path($action)) continue; // payload does not contain trigger path so end execution.
                
                $this->authenicate();
                $this->publish($action);

            }
            
            $this->log_request();
        }

        private function authenicate(){
            
            if($session_cookie != '') return; // session cookie was already created so exit authenication.
            
            $endpoint = $this->config['ouc_base_url'] . '/authentication/login';

            $config = array(
                'skin' => $this->config['skin'],
                'account' => $this->config['account'],
                'username' => $this->config['username'],
                'password' => $this->config['password']
            );

            $post_fields = http_build_query($config);

            $cURLConnection = curl_init($endpoint);
            curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
            curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

            $api_response = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
            $header  = curl_getinfo( $cURLConnection );
            curl_close($cURLConnection);

            $header_content = substr($api_response, 0, $header['header_size']);

            $pattern = "#Set-Cookie:\\s+(?<cookie>[^=]+=[^;]+)#m"; 
            preg_match_all($pattern, $header_content, $matches); 
            $this->session_cookie = implode("; ", $matches['cookie']);

        }

        private function publish($action){
            $endpoint = '/files/publish';
            
            $config = array(
                'site' => $action['site'],
                'path' => $action['publish_path'],
                'include_scheduled_publish' => 'true',
                'include_checked_out' => 'true'
            );
            

            $this->log_site = $action['site']; // set a site to use to create log files if logging is turned on.

            $this->send($endpoint, $config);
        }
        
        private function set_publish_path_map(){
            
            foreach($this->config['actions'] as $action){
                $this->publish_path_map[$action['site'] . $action['publish_path']] = 1;
            }
            
        }

        private function log_request(){
            if($this->config['log'] != 'true' || $this->log_site == '') return; // don't log when logging turned or if log_site not set
            
            $log_id = uniqid();

            $endpoint = '/files/save';

            $config = array(
                'site' => $this->log_site,
                'path' => $this->config['config_file'], // uses the config PCF to do a "save as" to a log file
                'new_path' => $this->get_root_relative_folderpath() . '_log/' . $log_id . '.txt',
                'text' => $this->raw_payload
            );

            $this->send($endpoint, $config);
        }
        
        private function send_next_webhook_request(){
            $next_webhook_url = trim($this->config['next_webhook_url']);
            
            if($next_webhook_url == '') return; // next_webhook_url not entered so just return.
            
            $this->payload->passed_through_rda = 'true';

            $connection = curl_init($next_webhook_url);
            curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($this->payload, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
            curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $api_response = curl_exec($connection);
            curl_close($connection);

        }

        private function send($endpoint, $config){

            $endpoint = $this->config['ouc_base_url'] . $endpoint;
            $post_fields = http_build_query($config);

            $connection = curl_init($endpoint);
            curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
            curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $this->session_cookie);

            $api_response = curl_exec($connection);
            curl_close($connection);
        }
        
        private function payload_contains_trigger_path($action){
            $site = $action['site'];
            
            $success = array(); // the success node in the webhook payload contains files that were published.
            if(!array_key_exists($site, $this->payload->success)) return false; // no success array so just return false.
            $success =  $this->payload->success->{$site};
            
            $published_paths = array();

            foreach($success as $i){
                if(!array_key_exists($site . $i->path, $this->publish_path_map)) $published_paths[] = $i->path; // only include paths that aren't also publish targets configured in this script to avoid publish recursion.
            }
            
            $trigger_paths = $action['trigger_path'];
            $trigger_paths = explode(',', $trigger_paths);
    
            foreach($trigger_paths as $trigger_path){
                $trigger_path = trim($trigger_path);
                $trigger_path = preg_replace('/(.)[\/]+$/', '$1', $trigger_path); // removes trailing slash unless the value is the string length is 1, for instance: '/'

                if($trigger_path == '') continue;
            
                foreach($published_paths as $path){
                    if($this->starts_with($path, $trigger_path)) return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        
        private function is_test_payload(){
            $account = $this->payload->account;
            
            if($account == '<account name>'){ // This is the account name value used by the test http request.
                echo $this->raw_payload;
                return true;
            }
            
            return false;
        }

        private function is_json($string){
            if(trim($string) == '') return false;
            json_decode($string);
            return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
        }

        private function starts_with($string, $startString){
            $len = strlen($startString); 
            return (substr($string, 0, $len) === $startString); 
        }
        
        private function get_root_relative_folderpath(){
            $result = $this->get_root_relative_filepath();
            $result = str_replace('\\', '/', $result);
            $result = preg_replace('/[^\/]+$/', '', $result);
            
            return $result;
        }
        
        private function get_root_relative_filepath(){
            $result = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

            return $result;
        }

    }

?>
```

For clarification: they have a service that manages cookies and they were able to turn those off, but there are a number of cookies that are persisting, and they are being generated by scripts leftover from years ago (I have no idea who wrote this code, or how old it is) and they need to be deleted. I just want to make sure that if I delete something it won't cause other bugs on the website

Comment: You can not just turn off cookies for a login that uses a cookie-based session, and then expect thing to still work properly. This would need to be made to work in combination with whatever service they have, to manage the cookies. If a user wants to login, but has not given consent to the session cookie yet - then that needs to happen first.

Comment: _"they have to because of privacy laws in Europe"_ - cookies that are essential for the basics workings of your site, are not "forbidden" per se to begin with. The user just has to be alerted to their use.

Answer (score 0):

Method to close all the cookies and sessions

i think you have start the sessions session_start()

```
session_start();
```

you can read the documentation here

//http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73484

To destory and close the sessions try the code below

the below method will help to unset the cookies serving in your php program

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
session_destroy();
```